# Is a 37 minute layover in MSP(Minneapolis Saint Paul International Airport) enough time?

Tags: layovers, msp

I am buying a flight to KIX (Kansai International Airport) from CMH (Columbus Ohio) which runs through MSP. I am an Australian Citizen currently in the USA. There is a layover time of 37 minutes at MSP.

The whole trip from CMH to KIX was made in a single purchase, but I did book it through student universe rather than the airlines themselves.

I will not have any checked baggage (only hand luggage).

Will I have enough time to make the tranfer?

I have 72 hours to cancel the flight if need be so I can rebook if necessary, but I'd rather not as the other options are a lot more expensive.

Comment: In addition to the information in the linked duplicate, I'd consider what happens if you don't make the flight, such as if your inbound flight experiences even a short delay. I'm not actually seeing Delta running a direct MSP-KIX flight at all, but if one exists, it likely only runs daily at best. So if you don't make that flight, you could be in for a long wait. Depending on your need to be in Japan at a particular time, that could be merely inconvenient or catastrophic, if a delayed arrival will mean missing something particularly important or cause a particular hardship.

Comment: Could you share the actual routing (at least the two flights into and out of MSP) and the date you intend to travel on? Are all flights on the same PNR / ticket? Some intermediaries will sell you flights that are actually booked separately as a single purchase, but those would give you no guarantee from the airlines in case you miss your connection.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/delta-air-lines-skymiles/76302-minimum-connection-transfer-time-minneapolis-st-paul-msp-definitive-thread-18.html) the MCT (minimum connection time) at MCT for domestic to international is 35 minutes if both flights are Delta. That means they think you should be able to make it, but that seems awfully tight. The chances you would be re-routed or re-booked on an alternative route or date are quite significant.

Comment: @jcaron The flight originates in CMH (Columbus Ohio), then goes to MSP, then goes to Haneda(HND), then to KIX. I will be leaving CMH on the 16th of december. I definitely need to be in Japan by the 19th so I could afford a day of delay but no more. All the flights are booked on the same ticket, the first two flights are with delta and the last flight is with all nippon airways.